# How do Inquire and Scrutinize differ?

Tags: octopath-traveler

These two path actions seem to yield the same results, except that Alfyns Inquire doesn't have a chance of failure.

What reasons are there to use [Scrutinize](https://octopathtraveler.fandom.com/wiki/Scrutinize) instead of [Inquire](https://octopathtraveler.fandom.com/wiki/Inquire)? Do you get better information from Scrutinize because it has a chance of failure?

If so, should I be running a team consisting of characters with only Noble path actions when in town?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though they both grant the same information the key difference is that using scrutinize allows you to access some information at lower levels than inquire would.  Inquire requires you to be at a certain level to work, but it is a guaranteed successes, where scrutinize can be attempted at a lower level, but risking the reputation hit that a failure incurs.